# Change Chatter Post when adding Products to reflect new custom field instead of standard Annual Amount field

Tags: chatter, opportunity

I want to replace "John Doe changed Annual Amount from **$0.00** to **$500.00**" chatter post on Opportunities with a value from my own custom field instead of the original "Annual Amount" field.

In other words I'm no longer using the Annual Amount standard field but made my own custom field but want the Chatter post to use the value from that custom field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just need to edit your Chatter Feed Tracking settings. Go to Setup > Customize > Chatter > Feed Tracking. Select the Opportunity object and then uncheck the fields you don't want and check the ones you do want.

[image]